# How to determine how much data have been read by XmlTextReader?

Tags: c#, .net, networkstream, xmltextreader

As I'm processing the XML, how can I determine how much data I have already processed, whether in bytes or in characters?  If the underlying stream were a `FileStream`, it would be easy.  How can I do it with an underlying `NetworkStream`?

Performance and memory considerations are very important.

```
NetworkStream reportStream = GetStream();
using (var bufferStream = new BufferedStream(reportStream))
{
  using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(bufferStream))
  {
    while (xmlTextReader.Read())
    {
      // TODO check how much data have been read already
      // bufferStream.Position and bufferStream.Length don't work 
      // because NetworkStream doesn't support them by design

      // process XML data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the stream into another and count?

Comment: `Read()`: Reads the next node from the stream.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeiLevenkov

Comment: Its not directly relevant for your use case (unless you _know_ your input is linarized!) but worth noting that XmlTextReader implements IXmlLineInfo https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.ixmllineinfo(v=vs.110).aspx which can get you your current position in Line / Char (_on line_) format which may be useful for future searchers of this question.

Comment: thanks, @tolanj.  I had considered the approach but realized that it would require significant overhead in keeping track of the size given that the length of each line is not uniform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @AlexeiLevenkov, I implemented a simple stream wrapper for my use case.

```
public class CountingStream : Stream
{
    private Stream _stream;
    private long _totalBytesRead;
    private long _totalBytesWritten;

    public CountingStream(Stream stream)
    {
        _stream = stream;
        _totalBytesRead = 0;
        _totalBytesWritten = 0;
    }

    public long TotalBytesRead { get { return _totalBytesRead; } }
    public long TotalBytesWritten { get { return _totalBytesWritten; } }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        _stream.Flush();
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        return _stream.Seek(offset, origin);
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        _stream.SetLength(value);
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int bytesRead = _stream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
        _totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
        return bytesRead;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        _totalBytesWritten += count;
        _stream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return _stream.CanRead; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return _stream.CanSeek; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return _stream.CanWrite; }
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { return _stream.Length; }
    }

    public override long Position
    {
        get { return _stream.Position; }
        set { _stream.Position = value; }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!disposing)
                return;
            if (_stream == null)
                return;

            try
            {
                Flush();
            }
            finally
            {
                _stream.Close();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _stream = null;
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If performance is a concern, you should consider overriding *all* the virtual methods of `Stream` to call to the same methods of the underlying instance. Many streams provide implementations with performance enhancements that are superior to the default `ReadByte` implementation, for example.